# Usage of videojs-contrib-ads with react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, ads, video.js, react-typescript, video-ads

Can anyone please provide a detailed example of using **videojs-vast-vpaid with react + typescript** as a plugin of videojs.
I tried following approach
(Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-vast-vpaid)

```
videojs.plugin('ads-setup', function (opts) {
    var player = this;
    var adsCancelTimeout = 3000;
 
    var vastAd = player.vastClient({
      //Media tag URL
      adTag: "http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?env=....",
      playAdAlways: true,
      //Note: As requested we set the preroll timeout at the same place than the adsCancelTimeout
      adCancelTimeout: adsCancelTimeout,
      adsEnabled: !!options.adsEnabled
    });
});
```

I tried adding this code to my class component but it didn't go well as *this* will refer to the class component context.

Comment: Hi, stack overflow works best when you try to write some code yourself, it doesn't work, you add it here, and then we comment on it

Comment: thanks @WurmD. I've updated my question please correct me.

Comment: I don't actually know the answer :). But now at least someone who knows is more likely to answer ^_^